# derivative of trace of product of a matrix by its transpose

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, transpose

let A be a p by n matrix.
I am stuck with finding the derivative below as part of my matrix calculations and need help with it please:

$$\frac{d}{dA}tr(AA^T)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) is an excellent resource for this sort of problem. In 2.5 it says
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{Tr}[F(A)]}{\partial A}=f(A)^T,$$ where $\partial F(x)/\partial x = f(x)$ holds for scalar $x$.

The cookbook continues from this fact and directly addresses your question in (115), which states
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{Tr}(A^T A)}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial \mathrm{Tr}( AA^T)}{\partial A}=2A.$$